# Python - get number of folder in list if file was found

Tags: python, for-loop

How i can get number of folder in my list when folder was found? - For example:
[Folder1, Folder2, Folder3]
I open all folders contained in this list by:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    pass
```

And in this folders i have something to find, example: file name in Folder2 -> xxx.png
When i was found this i wanna get get the number of Folder2 in my list i.e 1 `([Folder1, Folder2, Folder3])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this example:

```
import os

# folder path
dir_path = r'E:\account'
count = 0
# Iterate directory
for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
    # check if current path is a file
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
        count += 1
print('File count:', count)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.